# how to print the value stored in a variable inside a class

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to print the data sored in self.datafame but it's not working inside the class and function and outside the class it gives me an error self is not defined. Anyone who know how to print it.

```
class CustomDataSet(Dataset):
def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform):
    self.root_dir = root_dir
    self.transform = transform
    self.dataframe = pd.read_csv(csv_file, low_memory=False)

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.dataframe)

def __getitem__(self, idx):
    if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        idx = idx.tolist()
    img_path = self.dataframe.iloc[idx, 15]
    image = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")

    tensor_image = self.transform(image)
    return tensor_image
```

The error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <cell line: 19>()
     16         tensor_image = self.transform(image)
     17         return tensor_image
---> 19 print(self.dataframe)

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: That print statement in the error isn't in your code provided, also indentation matters and class methods need to be indented under the class declaration.

Comment: @josh-stackoverflow the indentation is correct

Comment: In that case please see @Mitchnoff's answer

Answer (score 2):

in your example you have

```
    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [33], in <cell line: 19>()
     16         tensor_image = self.transform(image)
     17         return tensor_image
---> 19 print(self.dataframe)
```

As your error, which from what I'm seeing you are printing this right after your class definition.

This is trailing outside of a function. When accessing an object's variable, you want to call the object's variable name and then the attribute you are trying to access. For example, if you did:

```
custom_dataset = CustomDataSet("../path/to/file", "my_root_dir", "my_transform")

# you can then do:
print(custom_dataset.dataframe)
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I have solved the issue, sorry for late reply